# Ommitting "required" attribute from Sitelinks Searchbox markup

Tags: schema.org, json-ld, google-rich-snippets, search-form

When implementing Google's [Searchlinks Searchbox](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/sitelinks-searchbox) feature, does it matter whether or not the corresponding form markup includes a `required` attribute? Or, is it safe to exclude that element while still specifying the `query-input` value as `required name=q`.

My JSON-LD and the corresponding markup are as following:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "WebSite",
  "url": "http://www.examplesite.com/",
  "potentialAction": {
    "@type": "SearchAction",
    "target": "http://www.examplesite.com/search/?q={q}",
    "query-input": "required name=q"
  }
}
</script>

<span class="search-display">
  <form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="/search/">
    <label for="s">Search</label>
    <input class="search-input" type="search" name="q" id="s" placeholder="Search..." autocomplete="off" />
    <div class="form-button-wrapper">
      <svg class="search-icon"><use xlink:href="#magnifying-glass" /></svg>
      <button type="submit">Search</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</span>
```

Comment: Did you find any documentation from Google that mentions this `required` value (as part of the `query-input` property)? In the linked page it doesn’t seem to be mentioned; it’s only part of the two JSON-LD examples.

Comment: @unor I can't find any documentation around this no; both the Microdata and JSON-LD examples have either a reference to the required element, or in the case of the Microdata a required attribute is present in form markup.